# Which permission is needed for a profile to be able to edit/set FLS

Tags: profile, fls

I am hitting a brick wall. Just can't find which permission needs to be enabled on a profile to allow assigned users to set up and/or edit FLS.

The issue is that due to policy restrictions I can't be assigned with Admin profile but need to do some modifications and have the permission to edit profiles, I've already managed to set up some permissions needed for the task but i just can't find this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly after posted the question I found the answer: Customize Application.

if anyone stumbles on this there's a [knowledge base article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000198725&language=en_US) which lists all the system permissions.